# (AWS) How to share SSH keys between multiple computers?

Tags: ssh, amazon-web-services, ssh-keys

I own multiple laptops and I am trying to connect to an instance I have set up in AWS. I have no problem SSHing into the instance on the first laptop, but when I send the private key to one of my other laptops, I get access denied (Load key "testkey.pem": invalid format). AWS only allows me to download 1 key at instance creation, so how can multiple computers connect to this instance?

Thanks

Comment: Private keys are called that way because they are private. Each user should have his own key pair. [Avoid Sharing Key Pairs for EC2](https://cloudonaut.io/avoid-sharing-key-pairs-for-ec2/).

Comment: Exactly how did you 'send' the file? If the destination copy is truly a copy, line for line and char for char, it should work. If the destination is Windows, be careful not to use software like notepad that adds a BOM-b to the beginning of the file -- that makes it NOT an exact copy, and invalid. @harrymc: this Q is not multiple users, it is one user with multiple machines